# websphere 7 Debug Port: 0.0.0.0

Tags: debugging, websphere, ibm-jdk

I'm using Webshpere 7 and I can't connect my debugger to Webshphere.

I've tried this on the command line...

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:3389 Test
```

Using 0.0.0.0 in the address makes it work!! I can connect from out side the machine.

This only seems to be the case with Websphere 7(IBM JDK 1.6), Websphere 6 (IBM JDK 1.5) does not have this "feature"

The Webpage for Websphere (/ibm/console) does not let me put this in to the console page.

```
Application servers > server1 > Debugging service
```

The "JVM debug port" on this page does not let me enter a 0.0.0.0:7777 as the port number.

Can anyone tell me where I can enter this value?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Sles Linux does not expose a port outside the box.

So by setting the debug port in WS to 7777 via the webpage(IBM/console) only exposes the port internally to the box.
To expose it you need to enter “0.0.0.0:7777”, but the web page does not allow this as a value.

So to change it by hand go to this file on the box...

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/WRSProfile/config/cells/WRSNodeCell/nodes/WRSNode/servers/server1/server.xml

Then replace 7777 with 0.0.0.0:7777 in the file. (there are 3 places to change this in the file)

```
 <services xmi:type="debugservice:DebugService" 
 xmi:id="DebugService_1331818723840" enable="true" 
 jvmDebugPort="0.0.0.0:7777" 
 jvmDebugArgs="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,
 server=y,suspend=n,
 address=0.0.0.0:7777" 
 BSFDebugPort="4444" BSFLoggingLevel="0"/>
...
 <jvmEntries xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_1183122130078" 
 verboseModeClass="false" verboseModeGarbageCollection="false" 
 verboseModeJNI="false" maximumHeapSize="1024" runHProf="false" 
 hprofArguments="" debugMode="true" 
 debugArgs="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,
 server=y,suspend=n,
 address=0.0.0.0:7777" 
 genericJvmArguments="">
```

Then stop and start the server.

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin # ./stopServer.sh server1
```

..

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin # ./startServer.sh server1
```

You can now connect a debugger to the machine!